# Need to prevent unwanted repositories

Tags: git, version-control, repository

Git - How to prevent unwanted repositories in developer system.

Hi all, I'm new to git. I started using git a few months ago and installed git-lab internally on a local server. I have added several git users who are all working with me. Now how can I ensure that they will not push from their personal github account.

Comment: Just being curious: Why do you need your repositories hosted on premise? Why not just get a payed-for plan from github and spare yourself the hussle maintaining a server and wasting resources?

Comment: Good choice but my adviser told like it is better than paid plan.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "push from their personal github account". Github credentials obviously would not make them login to your gitlab instance.

Comment: I said "push from their personal github account" for an example. it may github or any other cloud repositories. i hope you helped me lot thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done in gitlab by inviting your new company users into the repositories they are supposed to work on. You will have a list of contributors that you can fine-tune permission-wise according to your needs.

[image: Permissions editor]

According to the permissions you give those users they will be able - or not - to create repositories of their own. This is your tool to prevent anybody from creating projects at will.

Also you may want to have a look at the gitlab documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/).

Comment: it is very useful for me and i have a query which is complicated to me but i think not you. Once i added a employee as a Developer for my git lab repository he can clone the package into his desktop. so he may get a chance to upload any other cloud repository with out my knowledge. Am i right @harmonica141 ?

Comment: Wait, you are mixing up two things: 1) Yes, your dev can clone and do his thing on the repo, write code (in this repo!) and you can only stop him from merging it by enforcing pull requests on certain branches and review the code (which should be done anyway). But that is what you want because this is the way collaborative development on git is done. 2) No, he can not open any new repos because you add the collaborators on a per-repo basis whilst you keep managing the repos. They are basically locked in inside their repos. See permissions here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html

Comment: Now i understood what i have to do. i'll follow what you have suggested